# Compile .cpp and .lib into a shared .so library in WINDOWS

Tags: c++, compilation, .so, .lib

I'm kind of a noob in these things.

I have a .cpp file that uses functions from a .lib library (and its relative .h header file). In CLion I manage to run the program fine, but I need to compile it as a .so library because I want to use the functions defined in the .cpp in a python program.

Do you guys know how to do it?

Comment: Windows uses DLLs for shared libraries.  You have 3 choices gcc/g++ using the MinGW tool-chain or Microsoft Visual Studio using the either the native tool-chain or clang.

Comment: @RichardCritten yeah, that's what I read, but I don't understand what I need to do, since I do not have a .dll, but only .libs. g++ doesn't see the .lib files when I try linking them with the -l argument

Comment: You can try this: https://www.baeldung.com/jni

Comment: @Minato The page you shared talks about Java and .dylib, not Python and .lib